# SOFU included in Stack Exchange 2.0?

Tags: support, stack-exchange

Will the Super User, Stack Overflow and Server Fault sites be put under the umbrella of the new [Stack Exchange 2.0](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/changes-to-stack-exchange/)? Or will they stay separate?

Comment: Triology - The study of trilogies.

Comment: Looks like someone wiped out the **[trilogy]** tag as well. @pol

Comment: @random, that was me.  I did it in the middle of the night (United States Eastern time) a few days ago, since there were more `so-family` tags around than all similar-but-not-the-same tags (that I could find) put together.  I figured it fell under this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45555/retag-request-or-possibly-untag-request-sofaq-official/45562#45562

Comment: And it was fun pointing out that it was by popular demand. Though it was always some kind of thing to have the now four sites be named as a trilogy. So very HHG2TG. @pop

Comment: @random: I see... well, now that everything's consolidated, retagging `so-family` -> `trilogy` shouldn't be hard, if that's the direction people want to go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The combined Stack Exchange/Stack Overflow teams are integrating the best from both platforms into a new, faster, more versatile platform (Stack Exchange 2.0). While, technically, the trilogy sites will be running along with the "Stack Exchange 2.0" larger community of sites, they will almost certainly be running their own "special version" of software for the foreseeable future. There's just too many performance optimizations specific to those sites to just switch platforms mid-stream. But the new sites will be created under the new platform.

There's also the issue of how the new communities will be created. The trilogy sites already have well-defined communities so, obviously, they will not need the "Site Proposal/Commitment" process to form viable communities.

But there are lots of cool infrastructure changes in the works (like API work, etc) that will bring many cool, new capabilities to *all* the sites, SO/SF/SU included.

Answer (score 2):

I can see no foreseeable reason why StackOverflow and StackExchange must interact at all, or be part of the same umbrella.

While it does say that the two code bases are being merged, and most like StackOverflow and the other 2 will help to promote the new StackExchange sites, I highly doubt that any huge changes will be coming to StackOverflow because of StackExchange.

Comment: You will also note that the new Stack Exchange policy does NOT OPEN SOURCE the code. That is all.

Comment: Well I would look some form of interacting to solve all discussion on web-apps and gadgets on SU. Having the sites at least under the same umbrella will make it easier to redirect users to other SE-sites